# Difficulty creating a mock 'sink' for testing purposes in Rust

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

## Context

I have a function that will use rayon to paralellize some work. Each thread should write its output to a separate consumer. In practice, these consumers will usually write to (separate) files on disc. For testing, I want them to append to vectors, which I can then make assertions on.

## Problem

In fact I hit an issue even with a serial version of this code.
The function I want to test is `func_under_test`. I want `get_sink` to create and hand out a new 'sink' (a `Vec<i32>`) each time it is called, which will be inside `func_under_test`. But I also want to keep a reference to these vectors in my `main` function, so I can make assertions on them. I've tried writing this:

```rust
fn func_under_test<GetSink, F>(
    mut get_sink: GetSink
)
where
    GetSink: FnMut(usize) -> F,
    F: FnMut(i32) -> (),
{

    let idxs : Vec<usize> = (0..2).collect();
    idxs.iter().for_each(|&i| {
        let mut sink = get_sink(i);
        sink(0i32);
        sink(1i32);
        sink(2i32);
    });
}

fn main() {

    let mut sinks : Vec<&Vec<i32>> = vec![];
    let get_sink = |i: usize| {
        let mut sink : Vec<i32> = vec![];
        sinks.push(&sink);
        move |x : i32| sink.push(x)
    };

    func_under_test(get_sink);

    assert_eq!(**sinks.get(0).unwrap(), vec![0i32, 1i32, 2i32]);
}
```

But I get this compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `sink` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:20
   |
20 |     let mut sinks : Vec<&Vec<i32>> = vec![];
   |         --------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `sinks`
...
23 |         sinks.push(&sink);
   |         -----------^^^^^-
   |         |          |
   |         |          borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `sink` is borrowed for `'1`
24 |         move |x : i32| sink.push(x)
25 |     };
   |     - `sink` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `sink` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
20 |     let mut sinks : Vec<&Vec<i32>> = vec![];
   |         --------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `sinks`
...
23 |         sinks.push(&sink);
   |         -----------------
   |         |          |
   |         |          borrow of `sink` occurs here
   |         argument requires that `sink` is borrowed for `'1`
24 |         move |x : i32| sink.push(x)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---- move occurs due to use in closure
   |         |
   |         move out of `sink` occurs here
```

Am I correct in thinking that I need to use something like an `Rc` in this context, since I need to have two references to each `Vec<i32>`?
Since only one of those references needs to be mutable, do I need to use `Rc<Cell<Vec<i32>>>` in one case, and just `Rc<Vec<i32>>` in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the answer to this. The thread doing the testing needs to have access to the inner vectors, and so does the thread that is populating this. So they need to be wrapped in an `Arc` and a `Mutex`. But the outer vector does not, since it is only borrowed by the `get_sink` closure.

So `sinks` can have type `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>`.

Anyway, I can write this and it does compile and behave and expected:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn func_under_test<G, S>(
    get_sink: G)
where
    G: Fn(&usize) -> S + Sync,
    S: FnMut(i32) -> (),
{
    let idxs : Vec<usize> = vec![0, 1, 2];

    idxs.par_iter().for_each(|i| {
        let mut sink : S = get_sink(i);
        for j in 0..3 {
            sink(j + 3*(*i) as i32);
        }
    });
}

fn main() {

    let sinks : Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>> = vec![
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![])),
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![])),
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![])),
    ];

    let get_sink = |i: &usize| {
        let m : Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>> = sinks.get(*i).unwrap().clone();
        move |x: i32| {
            m.lock().unwrap().push(x);
        }
    };
    
    func_under_test(get_sink);

    assert_eq!(*sinks.get(0).unwrap().lock().unwrap(), vec![0, 1, 2]);
    assert_eq!(*sinks.get(1).unwrap().lock().unwrap(), vec![3, 4, 5]);
    assert_eq!(*sinks.get(2).unwrap().lock().unwrap(), vec![6, 7, 8]);
}
```

It also seems like `G` implements the correct traits here: it is `Sync`, since it needs to be shared between threads. But is is *not* `Send`, since it does not need to send information between threads.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use an `Arc<Mutex<i32>>` to share mutable access to the vectors. (`Rc` is not thread-safe.)

A tidier solution would be [`typed_arena::Arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/2.0.1/typed_arena/struct.Arena.html), which would allow you to write essentially the code you tried, but with the roles swapped: the `Vec<i32>`s are always owned by the arena (thus it outlives `func_under_tests`). Then, after *all* of the references to the arena are gone, you can convert it into a vector of its elements.

```rust
use typed_arena::Arena;

fn main() {
    let sinks: Arena<Vec<i32>> = Arena::new();
    let get_sink = |_i: usize| {
        let sink_ref = sinks.alloc(Vec::new());
        move |x| sink_ref.push(x)
    };

    func_under_test(get_sink);

    assert_eq!(sinks.into_vec()[0], vec![0i32, 1i32, 2i32]);
}
```